# tutorial/example of megamenu in k9?

Tags: kentico, megamenu

I need help in creating megamenu for kentico 9 v9.0.13

i read through Kentico 9 Documentation but didnt find any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
AJ

Comment: No need to cross post on SO and DevNet.  As long as your post on SO is tagged with "kentico" it will automatically be brought into the Kentico DevNet.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the idea also from the older version [article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/creating-a-mega-menu-(step-by-step)) or, you can also use the [hierarchical viewer](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/implementing-multi-level-responsive-navigation-using-a-hierarchical-transformation) - maybe it will fit your needs too.